# Ruby script 'Killed'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I am running a ruby script from the command line. The script downloads a file (15 MB), unzips it, parses it as JSON and then populates a mysql db with it.

When I run it, I get a simple 'Killed' message back. What's going on? How can I find out what the problem is?

I am using it on an EC2 micro instance.

Thanks

Here's the script

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'zlib'
require 'json'

require_relative '../db/db.rb'

dl = open('........')
ex = Zlib::GzipReader.new dl
json = JSON.parse ex.read
events = json['resultsPage']['results']['event']

puts "starting to parse #{events.count} event(s)..."
created = 0
updated = 0

events[1..10].each do |event|
    performances = event['performance']
    performances.each do  |performance|
        ar_show = Show.find_or_initialize_by_songkick_id performance['id']
        ar_show.artist_name = performance['displayName']
        ar_show.new_record? ? created += 1 : updated += 1
        ar_show.save!
    end
end

Import.create :updated => updated, :new => created
puts "complete. new: #{created}   -   updated: #{updated}"
```

Comment: Just get the message 'Killed'. How do I find stack trace?

Comment: There is a possibility of OOM (out of memory) killing.  Check /var/log/messages for errors.

Comment: I am sure EC2 admin killed it for some reason. like too much memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost certainly running out of memory, as a micro instance doesn't have much memory or swap space available. I've had this happen with Perl programs. Dynamic languages can use a lot of memory when processing large chunks of data.

The best way to test this theory is to spin up a small or large instance for under an hour (so you won't pay much for it) and try the script there. If it runs, you know that a micro instance is too small for your program to run on.

Comment: Thanks. I checked my microinstance and it has 400 mb of RAM that is free. My script downloads 15 MB of data and parses it as JSON. Do you think that is enough to make it OOM?

Comment: Damnn...you are right. I did cat /proc/meminfo every second while the script was running and free mem went from 416 MB to 6 MB. LOL.

Comment: Yep; I ran into the same problem using Grunt to uglify a file. I ran `while sleep 1; do cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree; done;` and it was interesting watch the memory dwindle down until the output was `bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` :D